# D3.js -- How do I update dataset via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a dataset with 11 different variables (csv file with 12 columns). I want to be able to select a certain column for my scatterplot, but I'm having some difficulties. Please bear with me, as JavaScript is not my strong suit (obviously). Here's what I attempted:

```
<div class="variables" id="fixedacidity" onclick="drawPlot('fixedacidity');">
    <h1>fixed acidity</h1>
</div>
<div class="variables" id="volatileacidity" onclick="drawPlot('volatileacidity');">
    <h1>volatile acidity</h1>
</div>
<div class="variables" id="citricacid" onclick="drawPlot('citricacid');">
    <h1>citric acid</h1>
</div>
<div class="variables" id="residualsugar" onclick="drawPlot('residualsugar');">
    <h1>residual sugar</h1>
</div>
etc ...
```

I made a simple menu that calls on the `drawPlot` function, but I'm having trouble trying to get the variable to pass on correctly.

Relevant d3/javascript:

```
function drawPlot(selectedVar){

$(".visarea").html("");

var wineVar = selectedVar;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 860 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0,10]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(10);


var chart1 = d3.select(".visarea").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("red.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.wineVar = +d.wineVar;
    d.quality = +d.quality;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.wineVar; })).nice();
  y.domain([0,10]).nice();

  chart1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(wineVar);

  chart1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Rated Quality")

  chart1.selectAll(".red.dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "red dot")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.wineVar); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.quality); })
      .style("fill", "red");

});
}
```

Although the variable gets passed on to the function, `d.wineVar`, as expected, does not return the desired value, and thus the chart does not draw the correct values.  Can anyone recommend a workaround for this? It seems so simple, yet I've spent hours failing trying to figure this out.

Sample of red.csv:

```
fixedacidity,volatileacidity,citricacid,residualsugar,chlorides,freesulfurdioxide,totalsulfurdioxide,density,pH,sulphates,alcohol,quality
7.4,0.7,0,1.9,0.076,11,34,0.9978,3.51,0.56,9.4,5
7.8,0.88,0,2.6,0.098,25,67,0.9968,3.2,0.68,9.8,5
7.8,0.76,0.04,2.3,0.092,15,54,0.997,3.26,0.65,9.8,5
```

[image: Image of what I'm trying to accomplish. The first dataset, fixedacidity, gets drawn up fine. I'm having difficulties trying to get the menu to correctly show its respective dataset. "Rated Quality" will always be the data for the Y-axis.]
Image of what I'm trying to accomplish. The first dataset, fixedacidity, gets drawn up fine. I'm having difficulties trying to get the menu to correctly show its respective dataset. "Rated Quality" will always be the data for the Y-axis.

Comment: What does `d.wineVar` mean? I can't see it in `red.csv`. It is expected just one of menu (FIXED ACIDITY, VOLATILE ACIDITY.. and so on)?

Comment: @JinyoungKim wineVar is the variable holding the desired column name-- passed down to the function. In D3, d.foo extracts the column that's titled 'foo.'

Comment: @Han, look at Klaujesi answer, you should not use dot notation for variables. Here is a good reading for improving your knowledge of dot and bracked notation in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: Must-read to work with D3js: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You has wrong variable reference, here:

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.wineVar = +d.wineVar;        //  <---------Here
    d.quality = +d.quality;
  });
```

change by:

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.wineVar = +d[wineVar];       // <----------Here
    d.quality = +d.quality;
  });
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! It get's a bit confusing at times as I am learning Python, PHP, Ruby, and Javascript all at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is the obvious issue pointed out by [klaujesi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631451/683977) about data extraction. But there are more issues with your code.

I would say you need to adapt your approach to the way d3.js works. Currently you will add a new svg on each call to the function, caused by this line in your code: `d3.select(".visarea").append("svg")`

I usually have some init code wrapped in one function, which creates the svg and sets ups everything static. Then there is an update function which will handle input changes to show different data, use different scales etc.

The nice thing about d3.js is that you can control very easily what's to happen with newly introduced data via `.enter()` and removed data via `.exit()`.

Comment: You right, code is not optimized. On every call, function clear the div: $(".visarea").html(""); and recreate all again.

Comment: Missed that one. That's a way to make it work, but not to make it shine :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, really appreciate the help. It amazes me how random strangers on the internet are always willing to help. <3

Comment: @pintxo You wouldn't happen to have any tutorials that will help me with the reapproach?

Comment: @HanIsaiahYoon: A good place to start is usually the d3.js examples gallery. Pick the one visualization you are interested and start reading and understanding what they do. Mikes homepage is also a good start: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/. Also, please read this paper https://data3.mprog.nl/course/15%20Readings/60%20Reading%206/Bostock_D3.pdf